# Declare map into function throws Data location must be "storage", "memory" or "calldata" for variable, but none was given

Tags: solidity

I have this function to check if an array has duplicates:

```
function hasDuplicates(uint256[] memory _array) internal pure returns (bool) {
    mapping(uint256 => bool) seen;

    for (uint256 i = 0; i < _array.length; i++) {
        if (seen[_array[i]]) {
            return true;
        } else {
            seen[_array[i]] = true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

but I get `Data location must be "storage", "memory" or "calldata" for variable, but none was given.` when I try to define `mapping(uint256 => bool) seen;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not allowed in solidity. You can't dynamically define mappings inside a function as it can be only defined as a storage variable.

**From [docs](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.14/types.html#mapping-types) :**

[image]

By storage reference it means something like this:

```
contract a {
    mapping(uint256 => bool)  aseen;

function hasDuplicates(uint256[] memory _array)
    internal
    
    returns (bool)
{
    mapping(uint256 => bool) storage seen = aseen;

    for (uint256 i = 0; i < _array.length; i++) {
        if (seen[_array[i]]) {
            return true;
        } else {
            seen[_array[i]] = true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
}
```

Comment: Ok thank you, from the error output wasn't clear